# DateTimePicker only will allows user to select date by clicking on calendar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetimepicker

I am having an issue with the `dateTimePicker` class. I need to have the `DateTimePicker` empty on construct, which I have achieved via this:

```
dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Now; // Ensures no future dates are set.
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;   
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " ";
```

My issue is that now the user has to actually *click* on the on the calendar to enter a date, rather than using the up down keys, or type. Is there anyway I can initialize `dateTimePicker1` to `" "`  as I have in my constructor, but also allow the user to 'Activate' it by using he arrow keys opposed to clicking on the calendar?

My `ValueChanged` changed event

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss";
                if (dateTimePicker1.Checked == true)
                {
                    dateTimePicker1.Enabled = true;
                    dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
                }
                else if (dateTimePicker1.Checked == false)
                {
                    dateTimePicker1.Enabled = false;
                    dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                    dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " ";
                }
            }
```

I know that `DateTimePicker` is not easily made nullable and in order so you have to right an extension of the class but this was a quick fix. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " " does not initialise the dateTimePicker to " ", it means the display format is empty.

Comment: @ajg  yes just the display format is empty not dateTimePicker I Was meaning its Initial value on construct .

Comment: Isn't there more code than this?  The date is never visible with that format.

Comment: @LarsTech Yes I have edited it to add my valueChanged event Handler .

Comment: Try putting dateTimePicker1.Checked = true and dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short in the PreviewKeyDown event.

Comment: @LarsTech Thankyou works exactly as I wanted. Much appreciated